# Is there a way or a work around to perform table joins in flutter using sqflite library?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-sqlite, sqflite

Normally when I'm starting to code something I do some research on what technologies I'm gonna use. But when I started using sqflite library I didn't need to do so because it has such a high rating and use at **flutter packages** site.

So as I just did a thing or two with this library I'm at the point where I will need to perform **table** joins. Based on the information I've found out about this library it is say it currently doesn't support table joins. What I want Is to be able to perform table joins using sqflite, for now I don't care weather is a work around to achieve this task. I just need a clue so I can go with it and continue to code on this project I'm working on. Thank you, posted with Love.

Answer (score 1):

> it is say it currently doesn't support table joins

I'm not sure where you got this (wrong) information;
sqflite supports whatever SQLite supports. JOINs are supported, maybe its syntax is specific/limited compared to MySQL or other SQL engine but you should be able to use any SQLite tutorial on SQLite and JOIN and use the `rawQuery` method:

- https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/
- https://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/joins/

In fact the JOIN keywords is not even necessary in SQLite, you can query on multiple tables and add a WHERE clause such as `table1.id = table2.other_id`.

```
SELECT album.title FROM album, artist WHERE album.artistId = artist.id
```

sqflite has not good documentation on that (it would imply re-documenting what https://sqlite.org does)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform table joins with moor_flutter packages easily . [Moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter)
and here is a [flutter moor blog link](https://resocoder.com/2019/07/17/moor-room-for-flutter-3-foreign-keys-joins-migrations-fluent-sqlite-database/). You will find Joining the tables using moor flutter packages in this blog.

Comment: Can I use moor together with sqflite? because I have already made forms for this app and the forms are working fine. The only problem is joining tables.

Comment: @James_22 `"The only problem is joining tables."` so did you use `query` / `rawQuery` methods?

Comment: And nothing happens when I do a right join with the table I want to join I just see a message saying something like "currently sqflite does not support table joins".

Comment: @James_22 `var result = await db.query('main left join second on main.id = second.main_id', 
      columns: ['name', 'city'],
    );` and for your case: https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Comment: @James_22 and the above `query` is used with the tables like those: `db.execute('create table main(id INT, name TEXT)');
    db.execute('create table second(id INT, main_id INT, city TEXT)');
`

Comment: @pskink Thank you man I'm trying your solution right now. I'll tell you the results soon.

Comment: @pskink My main table is called **persons** and my second table in this case is called **products** `query('persons left join products on persons.id = products.persons_id', columns: ['item_name', 'item_cost'],);` I'm getting this error `I/flutter (20724): AsyncSnapshot<List<Person>>(ConnectionState.done, null, Invalid argument(s))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the following way, you can also concatenate external variables

```
  var res = await example.database.rawQuery(
      "SELECT data1,data2,table2_id,table3_id FROM table1 AS a , table2 AS b WHERE a.table2_id = ${table2Id.toString()} AND a.table3_id = b.id ORDER BY a.table2_id DESC");
```